# Remove duplicate resources in different flavors of APK

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle, android-resources

I have an app which has 2 different flavors, lets say F1 and F2 and resources specific to these are kept in following folder sturcture:

res

- *drawable*
- *drawable-qualifier_for_F1*
- *drawable-qualifier_for_F2*

Now default folder "drawable" has default copy of all the resources and some of these are present in F1 and F2.
In my APK for F1 the default folder contains the same resource that is present in *drawable-qualifier_for_F1* folder.

How can I avoid this and only keep one copy of resource in my APK, that will be actually used, which in above case will be the one in d*rawable-qualifier_for_F1* folder.

Comment: right click 'Show in files' then put every drawable items to main drawable. then delete all other items in the drawable files of all the flavors. and File --> Invalidate changes / restart

Comment: Share your app build.gradle.

Comment: I don't understand completely your question. If you have a qualified drawable for F1, this one will be copied into your APK, not the default one.

Answer (score 0):

Create `values-qualifier_for_F1` and `values-qualifier_for_F2` folders in `res`. After that create `drawables.xml` files there with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="some_icon_for_F1_or_F2">@drawable/icon_from_default_folder</drawable>
</resources>
```